# Spherical coordinates on cartesian straight lines

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Compute the volume of the solid bounded by:

- the surface $(z+1)^2=x^2+y^2,$
- the surface $4z=x^2+y^2,$
- above the $xy$ plane.

I want to do it with spherical coordinates. However $\rho$ is difficult to express because it's no longer $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. $\rho$ should be a function of $\phi$ (the angle between the positive semi-axis $z$ and a ray $\overrightarrow{(0,0,0)(x,y,z)}$). $\phi$ will vary from $\arcsin \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right) $ to $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. And $\rho(\phi)$ varies from $1$ to $\sqrt{5}$.

Any ideas of how to do it by spherical coordinates? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always cast the problem in spherical polar coordinates, but there is a discontinuity in the gradient of $\rho(\phi)$ along the circle that is the intersection of the surfaces $(z+1)^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $4z = x^2 + y^2$. This will needlessly complicate the volume integral.

If I were allowed to, I'd use cylindrical polar coordinates instead of spherical, because of the cylindrical symmetry of the volume in question.

Comment: Actually now I see that those aren't straight lines (the inner surface is a parabolloid). I'll try to do it using cylindrical  coordinates and will tell you if I succeeded. Thanks.

Comment: I did this: Taking into account that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then $2\sqrt{z}\leq r\leq z+1$. Then the integral becomes:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{2\sqrt{z}}^{z+1}r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz = \frac{\pi}{3}$$